# Why are destructors necessary in C++?

Tags: c++, memory, raii, memory-management

Why must we use destructors to de-allocate memory in c++,

As we can use

```
delete or delete[]
```

Is it not true that all the memory used up by a program is released when the program terminates.

Comment: What if I make your objects in a loop that runs for as long as the program does (say creating drawing objects to refresh my window with)? And it isn't required for the OS to clean up, but there's a very good chance it will.

Comment: No.  Memory on the stack that your program is using is released when the program terminates, but memory that your program reserves on the heap is released when and only when use `delete` it.  If you do not `delete` it, you have a memory leak.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Destructors in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502052/destructors-in-c)

Comment: It is essential to the language's scope based, deterministic resource management. It allows you to control the lifetime of objects (and associated resources, if any) in a clear and simple way. It turns out that this is quite useful.

Comment: That depends on the OS, and even though that most OS frees all memory allocated by a program when exiting, you have to realize that your program is not being run alone, there are other people in the computer and the resources (Memory) are shared, so try to optimize then ;)

Comment: You are slightly confused about destructors and releasing memory, they are two different things. When used normally, `delete` will both call destructors and release memory, but you can release memory without having destructors called, and you can have destructor called without using `delete`.

Comment: @nhgrif: No, not true at all, assuming you have an operating system that is in any way competent.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Even if your OS resolves the memory leak, it's still a memory leak (in the scope of your program)! You might as well argue that memory leaks never exist because you can always turn off your computer to wipe all RAM; I don't think that this is a strawman -- the point is that the term "memory leak" does not inherently mean "memory leak that continues to exist for a specific amount of time"

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: It was a few months ago now, but I believe I was arguing with the statement *"but memory that your program reserves on the heap is released when and only when use delete it."*, not whether it should be called a memory leak when you don't.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: Oh, right: I hadn't even spotted that nuance in the original comment, to be honest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"we use destructors to de-allocate memory"*

What you are actually writing about are *deallocation functions* `operator delete` and `operator delete[]`.

*"Is it not true that all the memory used up by a program is released when the program terminates?"*

AFAIK this is OS specific, yet the point is not what happens after the program terminates. The point is about what happens *during the execution*. There are many applications that run for several hours or even weeks and memory leaks might have very unpleasant consequences in these (not that memory leaks wouldn't be unpleasant in terms of other programs).

When you program reaches the point, where the resources that you've allocated are not needed anymore, you should do your very best to free them using appropriate means. And once your program terminates: *Relying on OS cleaning your mess* doesn't seem to be much of a good practice  ;)

Comment: Relying on an OS which does not (at least memory-wise) try to clean up your mess is equally bad practice :)

Comment: @DanielFrey: My rule of thumb is: I always clean the mess I caused, regardless the environment :D

Comment: Of course, me too, but sadly not everyone thinks so. Therefore I want the OS to be a safety net, given that *even I* do make mistakes :-P

Answer (score 5):

Very often, it is not enough to get the memory back only after your program terminates. Most programs designed for continuous running need to allocate temporary memory of variable size, without a specific fame for that memory's life time. It is obvious that if you request memory and do not return it for a significant amount of time, your program will run out of memory, and terminate when it requests additional memory.

With this said, you can go long way without using destructors in C++ by allocating everything that you can allocate in the automatic area. The only time when you really need to use dynamic memory is when the lifetime of the object must extend past its allocation scope, but even then C++ containers would take care of most allocations for you (of course the implementation of the standard containers relies heavily on the constructor/destructor infrastructure of the C++ language).

Answer (score 2):

Destructors are guaranteed to be called if RAII is used. It is not like we have to use it, but it is generally a good idea to benefit from RAII because it allows for automatic resource management. In other words, if you write your program right, it won't have resource or memory leaks, so you don't even have to worry about it.

This is true not only for C++, but for other languages that have support for automatic resource management such as C#, Java, and even C (through non-standard extensions).

Basically, you need to read some book on C++ to understand the concept, probably. I also wrote a little article that might be helpful, see [here](http://lazarenko.me/2013/03/03/automatic-resource-management/).

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `delete` and `delete[]` are not destructors, they just call the destructors of the instances that are deleted (given that those do have destructors).

To answer your bigger question: The destructor of a class **can do more than just release memory**. For example, it might signal another program that it is about to close a connection or something.

Also, some programs **run "forever"** - or at least for as long as possible. I, for example, develop programs that are running on servers and they (hopefully) run for month. I do need to release memory (or other resources) as soon as possible otherwise the process will grow and eventually crash when the machine runs out of memory.